# Bootstrap page opening vertically halfway down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, broken-links

on this site: http://m.rebalancing-training.com the index.html page opens scrolled halfway down in Chrome, and 1/3 of the way down in Firefox. I tried using a #top anchored link to go to the page and it still opens half way down, altho of course should not have to do that. The other two finished links "Rebalancing" and "Training" behave as they should, it's only the index.html which is opening strangely.

Bootstrap v.3.3.4

any help appreciated

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Excellent point, and of course when the live page is fixed, the problem is not there anymore to benefit others. So - it's fixed now, here is the solution:

Comment: In bootstrap there is a page header div class called jumbotron. If that div appears again on the same page it will scroll automatically down to the second appearance of the class. There can only be one div classed jumbotron on a page.