# Sticky header crash on page load

Tags: html, css

I have a weird bug that is difficult to reproduce but really annoying. I have a sticky nav bar header which follow the scrolling of the page to stay on the top. In general it works ok, but...If I am in the bottom of the page, then refresh the page and push the bottom arrow while it is refreshing, the header "thinks" that the top of the page is the top of the visible space when I am in the bottom. As a result, the navbar stays in the middle of the page.

Here is the code:

```
<header class="sticky" id="top-header">....</header>

#top-header {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%) repeat scroll 0 0%, linear-gradient(to left, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#top-header.sticky {
    bottom: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested in Chrome and Mozilla. Latest versions in both.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `transition`, just to see if it makes the same? I have three fixed bars in a page, without hassles.

Comment: Just tested more and show that when it happens, above the limit that the header stack, the `class='sticky'` removed. When I scroll below the limit, the sticky class reappear. I will test it without the transition, but I don't think that will make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't have the rep to comment.

A similar issue was recently reported for a bootstrap set up (see: [Bootstrap page opening vertically halfway down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725832/bootstrap-page-opening-vertically-halfway-down)). OP described as opening halfway down, but when I looked at it the behaviour was similar to your description. The OP self posted an answer saying it was caused by the "jumbotron" class being used twice on a page.

Does this apply to you?

If not, then it sounds like a js issue.

Comment: I don't even use this class in the page. But thank you.